# Remove characters from list of strings using comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I would like to know how to remove certain characters from a list of strings.
In this case, I am trying to remove `numbers` of type `str` using list comprehension.

```
numbers = [str(i) for i in range(10)]
imgs_paths = [os.path.join(input_folder, f) for f in os.listdir(input_folder) if f.endswith('.jpg')]
foo_imgs_paths = [[e.replace(c, "") for c in e if c not in numbers] for e in imgs_paths]
```

The code above does not work, because it returns completely empty lists.

Comment: Tried running your code, but errors appear: `NameError: name 'os' is not defined`  `NameError: name 'input_folder' is not defined`

Comment: Since others won't have access to files in `input_folder`, it would be better to provide an example of list `imgs_paths` and the desired result for `foo_imgs_paths`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki this is just a portion of the code... to actually run it you need to add `import os` and `input_folder = "/some/folder/on/your/computer/"` before the code

Comment: yes, I did. then `imgs_paths` was an empty list since there was no jpg files in the folder I specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

If I understand your question right, a function might simplify it more than nested comprehension.

```py
"doj394no.jpg".replace("0","").replace("1","")... # "dojno.jpg"
```

If you have your list of files and list of characters to remove:

```py
files = [...]
numbers = "01234556789"

def remove_chars(original, chars_to_remove):
    for char in chars_to_remove:
        original = original.replace(char, "")
    return original

new_files = [remove_chars(file, numbers) for file in files]
```

### Option 2

If you *really* want to use comprehensions, you can use them to filter letters out without replace:

```py
numbers = "0123456789"
filename = "log234.txt"
[char for char in filename if char not in numbers] # ["l","o","g",".","t","x","t"]
# To return it to a string:
"".join([char for char in filename if char not in numbers]) # "log.txt"
```

In your case, it would be like so:

```py
numbers = [str(i) for i in range(10)]
imgs_paths = [os.path.join(input_folder, f) for f in os.listdir(input_folder) if f.endswith('.jpg')]
foo_imgs_paths = [
    "".join(char for char in img_path if char not in numbers)
    for img_path in img_paths
]
```

Comment: You don't need `numbers`, you could do `if not char.isdigit()` instead of `if char not in numbers`

Comment: @Jasmijn in this case yeah it would be easier I'm just thinking if they want to use a different list of removed characters like "_!~-" etc then it's easy to add

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a regular expression?

```
import re
re.sub(r'\d+', '', 'lo2g4.jpg')
'log.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just provide another solution:

```
old_str = "S11imone22.jpg"
new_str = old_str.translate(str.maketrans("", "", "0123456789"))
print(new_str) # Simone.jpg
```

I still prefer the **re** solution, which is faster